# Retrieve parent property name/path from the current binding context

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

That is much simpler than it may sound.

Imagine that I have a custom binding:

```
KO.bindingHandlers.custom = {
  init:function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, 
                context, bindingContext) {
    ...
  }
});
```

that is applied via HTML markup like this:

```
<div>
  <div data-bind="with: a">
    <span data-bind="custom: aa"></span>
  </div>
  <div data-bind="with: b">
    <span data-bind="custom: bb"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

where ViewModel structure is:

```
{
  root: {
    a: {
      aa: 100
    },
    b: {
      bb: 200
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to know, in `init` function who was the "daddy", so to speak, so that when `init` is taking care of `custom: bb` binding I'd like to know that property path is `root.b` (or get any suitable indication of that).

Using `bindingContext.$parent` doesn't help, obviously, as it contains `a` as well.

**Attempts**

So far the closest was to use `bindingContext.createChildContext` and pass name of the parent property in the binding (as in the first `custom` binding below):

```
<div>
  <div data-bind="with: a">
    <span data-bind="custom: {name: 'aa', parent: 'a'}"></span>
  </div>
  <div data-bind="with: b">
    <span data-bind="custom: bb"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Quite ugly.

**Note**

Note that the nesting level may be more than 1 - if there are nested `with` bindings "before" `custom` or `if` or `foreach` (you get the picture).

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: "Using bindingContext.$parent doesn't help, obviously, as it contains a as well" - please explain.  According to [KO documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html), `bindingContext.$parent` would give you `root` in your example.

Comment: `root` contains both `a` and `b`. I need to know which one was the parent of the current `custom` binding. Basically, when I am taking care of `aa` I want to know that `a` was its parent.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really tested this, but you could call a function like this from your custom binding to walk up the binding context stack and use `===` to figure out which property in the parent object matches the object the current context is bound against.

```
var getPath = function (bindingContext) {
    var parts = [],
        prev = bindingContext,
        i, n;

    for (i = 0, n = bindingContext.$parents.length; i < n; ++i) {
        var p = bindingContext.$parents[i];
        // find which property of p.$data corresponds to prev.$data
        var properties = Object.keys(p.$data);
        var matchingProperty = ko.utils.arrayFirst(properties, function (name) {
            return ko.unwrap(p.$data[name]) === prev.$data;
        });

        parts.unshift(matchingProperty || "could not determine this part");
        prev = p;
    }

    return parts.join(".");
};
```

I think it will only work with simple `with` expressions.  Compound `with` expressions will defeat this algorithm.